# Cypress: comparing values on page against each other

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm using Cypress and trying to verify that the website I'm testing is doing the correct calculations across 2 tables.  I am struggling to work out how to get hold of data from the page using cypress, and then perform validation on it

e.g.
{Value in Table 1} = {Value in table 2} + {Difference in table 2}

Sample (simplified) HTML attached.

I just don't get how to get hold of 3 'values' in cypress at the same time to perform checks on all 3 together.

[image: the tables]

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        table, th, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }</style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Current</th>
            <th>Value </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>585</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>537</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>48</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Future</th>
            <th>Value </th>
            <th>Difference </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>595</td>
            <td>+10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>467</td>
            <td>-70</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>108</td>
            <td>+60</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test you want to do is basically

```js
expect(currentValue).to.eq(futureValue - diffValue)
```

To do that across the table, use `.each()` command on the rows.

To extract the same row for each table, use the 2nd parameter of `.each()` which is the index.

```js
cy.get('table tbody').eq(0)     // current values table
  .find('tr')
  .each(($tr, currentRow) => {

    const currentCell = $tr.find('td')[1]
    const currentValue = currentCell.innerText

    cy.get('table tbody').eq(1)    // future values table
      .find('tr').eq(currentRow)   
      .then(($tr) => {

        const futureCell = $tr.find('td')[1]
        const futureValue = futureCell.innerText

        const diffCell = $tr.find('td')[2]
        const diffValue = diffCell.innerText

        expect(+currentValue).to.eq(futureValue - diffValue)
      })
  })
```

Answer (score 4):

Just so you know, many Cypress queries are just wrappers for `jQuery` query of the [same name](https://api.jquery.com/next/), so you can substitute directly inside the `.then()` callback.

```js
const currentVals = {};
const futureVals = {};
const offsets = {};

const rows = ['A', 'B', 'C']
rows.forEach((value) => {
  cy.get('@current').find('td').contains(value).then(keyCell => {
    currentVals[value] = +keyCell.next().text()
  });
  cy.get('@future').find('td').contains(value).then(keyCell => {
    futureVals[value] = +keyCell.next().text()
    offsets[value] = +keyCell.next().next().text()
  })
})
```

Also jQuery has [pseudo-selectors](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) that can be added to `selector` in `cy.get(selector)`

```js
const currentVals = {};
const futureVals = {};
const offsets = {};

const rows = ['A', 'B', 'C']
rows.forEach((value) => {
  cy.contains('table:first td', value).then(keyCell => {
    currentVals[value] = +keyCell.next().text()
  });
  cy.contains('table:last td', value).then(keyCell => {
    futureVals[value] = +keyCell.next().text()
    offsets[value] = +keyCell.next().next().text()
  })
})
```

Comment: So what is the '+' doing here?  it's not a notation I've seen before

Answer (score 3):

You can extract a value for each row in the current and future tables and save them to an Alias varaible.

The value arrays are easy to compare with the `deep.eq` comparison.

```js
function currentValue(row) {
  // calculate the row value for "current" table
  return +Cypress.$(row).find('td')[1].innerText
}

function futureValue(row) {
  // calculate the row value for "future" table
  const value = Cypress.$(row).find('td')[1].innerText
  const diff = Cypress.$(row).find('td')[2].innerText
  return value - diff
}

// extract current table values and save
cy.get('table:eq(0) tbody')
  .find('tr')
  .then(rows => [...rows].map(currentValue))
  .as('current')

// extract future table values and save
cy.get('table:eq(1) tbody')
  .find('tr')
  .then(rows => [...rows].map(futureValue))
  .as('future')

// compare values
cy.get('@current').then(current => {
  cy.get('@future').then(future => {
    expect(future).to.deep.eq(current)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks all for the answers. The code I had come up with is below which I think uses concepts from a couple of them. I had to 'work around' the final assert loop happening first by sticking it inside a `cy.get('body')` to put it on cypres' async queue. It felt like a dirty hack, but with your suggestions above I'll be able to remove that.  Many thanks all!

```
  cy.get('table').first().as('current');
  cy.get('table').last().as('future');

  const rows = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

  const currentVals = {};
  const futureVals = {};
  const offsets = {};
  rows.forEach((value) => {
    cy.get('@current').within((table) => {
      cy.get('td').contains(value).next().then((cell) => {
        currentVals[value] = Number(cell.text());
      });
    });
    cy.get('@future').within((table) => {
      cy.get('td').contains(value).next().then((cell) => {
        futureVals[value] = Number(cell.text());
      });
    });
    cy.get('@future').within((table) => {
     cy.get('td').contains(value).next().next().then((cell) => {
        offsets[value] = Number(cell.text());
      });
    });

  });

  cy.get('body').then(() => {
    rows.forEach((value) => {
      assert((currentVals[value] + offsets[value]) == futureVals[value]);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

So, with the simplified HTML you've provided, you can do something like the following.

The big picture answer is that you can store the data in a separate variable outside of your Cypress commands, and modify that data as you encounter the data in the table. I expect that much of the code below won't be directly applicable to a more real-world example, but I'll highlight what I'm doing below.

```js
it.only('foo', () => {
    const dataObj = {}; // declare Data Object as empty Object
    cy.visit('/foo');
    cy.contains('table', 'Current').within(() => { // get the table with Current values
      cy.get('tbody tr').each(($row) => { // Iterate through each Table Row
        cy.wrap($row)
          .children()
          .then(($children) => {
            // Add data to the Data Object, where the `Current` is the key, and `Value` is the value
            dataObj[$children[0].textContent] = $children[1].textContent;
          });
      });
    });
    cy.contains('table', 'Future').within(() => { // get the table with Future values
      cy.get('tbody tr').each(($row) => { // Iterate through each Table Row
        cy.wrap($row)
          .children()
          .then(($children) => {
            // Using `+` as a shorthand for integer conversion
            expect(+$children[1].textContent).equal(
              +dataObj[$children[0].textContent] + +$children[2].textContent
            );
          });
      });
    });
  });
```